# Python can't find module for import

Tags: python, import, module, python.net

I have a dll file that I need to import in Python. However when I try to load the assembly I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TEST_NET'

The assembly dll file is located in `C:\Program Files\TEST APP\APP 7.0` under the name `TEST_NET.Core.dll`

My code is the following:

```
app_version = "7.0"
app_library = "C:\Program Files\TEST APP\APP 7.0"

# load app assemblies... replace the path below with the installation
#   installation folder for your app installation.
# Import from .NET assemblies (both App and system)
sys.path.append(app_library)
clr.AddReference('TEST_NET.Core')
from TEST_NET.Core import*
```

The code was working well with a previous app version. But the new app that contains the file has return this issue where the module is not found when trying to import. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't import a file as a module

Comment: @TheDiamondCreeper as long as it's a python file, why not?

Comment: I know .py files can be imported, but I think he is trying to import .dll

Answer (score 0):

use ctypes to import a dll

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.WinDLL (r"C:\Program Files\TEST APP\APP 7.0\TEST_NET.Core.dll")
```